# Turn triple ratio into percent

Tags: ratio

I have this triple ratio:

**14:7:5**

How would one go about turning this into a percentage i.e something to the likes of this

**30%**

**20%**

**50%**

Comment: I don't think ratio is defined for more than $2$ quantities (numbers). So here you have a $50$%, the $(14:7)$, a $(14:5)$ and a $(7:5)$.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake sure you can have a ratio defined for more than two parts... this occurs all the time... for instance in baking.  You've probably seen something along the lines of "3 parts flour, 2 parts liquid, 1 part fat" for a simple biscuit recipe... that's a $3:2:1$ ratio.  If you want to scale up or down, you can do so by multiplying all parts by the same amount.  Transforming into percentages is just talking about "what part of the total volume" each ingredient is.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hmm.. I get what you mean though I would still view it as a set of 3:6, 2:6, 1:6 ratia, but ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by the total: $14 + 7 + 5 = 26$.

$$\frac{14}{26} = 0.538 = 53.8\%,$$ $$\frac{7}{26} = 0.269 = 26.9\%,$$ $$\frac{5}{26}= 0.192 = 19.2\%.$$

(N.B. All decimals and percentages rounded to 3 significant figures for simplicity.)